# For Each looping through Range, .Columns() number seems to change?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through a filtered set of data on a sheet and then for each entry on that sheet, looping through a filtered range on a second sheet in another workbook to return each entry for that "tag". For some reason, the .Columns() index seems to jump around. On the first iteration, it pulls Columns(1) and Columns(2) as expected, but on the next iteration, Columns(1) actually returns the value that should be in Columns(2), on the next iteration it Columns(1) actually pulls the value from Columns(3) and so on. Any advice on what I am missing is appreciated.

```
...
flLastRowOfSheet = flWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row of Fitting List sheet
Set flSelectionRange = flWs.Range("$A$1:$E$" & flLastRowOfSheet) 'Set range for filter on Fitting List

'-------------------------------------------------------------------
'---Loop through Settings and get all Tags--------------------------
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
For Each Rng In filRange
    If lastRow > filRangeRows Then 
        Exit For
    End If
    tag = Rng.Columns(1).Value2 
    zoneDescription = Rng.Columns(2).Value2
    pasteSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Value2 = tag 
    InsSum.Range("$P$9") = tag
    pasteSheet.Range("B" & lastRow).Value2 = zoneDescription 

    With flSelectionRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=tag, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
        Set flRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
    End With
    flRangeRowCount = flRange.Rows.Count 
    pasteSheet.Range("C" & lastRow).Value = flRangeRowCount & " Fitting List Entries Found" 

    Dim i As Integer 
    i = 1 
    For Each flRng In flRange 
        If flRange.Rows.Count < i Then 
            Exit For 
        ElseIf flRangeRowCount >= i Then 'Below is where it is not working as expected

            flTag = flRng.Columns(1).Value2
            flDescription = flRng.Columns(2).Value2
            Debug.Print "Zone Tag = " & tag & " Tag = " & flTag & " Description = " & flDescription
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next flRng
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
Next Rng
```

...
What I expect to see in Immediate Window:

> Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag = HFF837207 Description = SPG-600 Radiator
>   Cooling System Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag = MAJ837239 Description =
>   SPG-600 GENERATOR LUBE OIL FILTER STANDBY Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag =
>   MAJ837237 Description = SPG-600 GENERATOR LUBE OIL FILTER MAIN

Actual Output from Immediate Window:

> Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag = HFF837207 Description = SPG-600 RADIATOR
>   COOLING SYSTEM Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag = SPG-600 RADIATOR COOLING
>   SYSTEM Description = 22 Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag = 22 Description = C
>   Zone Tag = UA000251 Tag = C Description = UA000251

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flRng.Columns(1)` refers to the first column within a range. If the outer range `flRange` is multiple columns then `flrng.columns(1)` will change.

You can see that here in this quick example:

```
Sub testrange()
    Dim rg1 As Range
    Dim rg2 As Range

    Set rg1 = Range("A1:AA2")

    For Each rg2 In rg1
        Debug.Print rg2.Columns(1).Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew I must be missing something. I narrow the range on flRange and then use flRng.Columns(-3) and flRng.Columns(-4) and it works as expected. Thanks!